# Parse flat file in Mule 4 skipping header

Tags: mule4

How can we parse fixed length flat file skipping first few lines as header in Mule 4?

Input header:

```
HEADER
BOB  123 NEWYORK
TOM  456 DALLAS
```

I have tried using MIME type as application/flatfile

```
form: FIXEDWIDTH
id: 'record'
name: 'record'
values: 
- { name: 'name', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
- { name: 'code', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
- { name: 'city', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
```

Comment: What is the result of what you tried? Is "HEADER" a literal line in the input?

Comment: File is not getting parsed , runtime error in parsing. Flow is like Set Payload with MIME type application/flat file with schema and then use transform %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ( row,index ) -> {
 "name": row.name,
 "code": row.code,
 "city": row.city,
 "line": index
}

Comment: You should add the error message and the flow to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the header to the structure of the file.

Example:

```yaml
form: FLATFILE
structures:
- id: 'file'
  name: file
  data:
  - { idRef: 'header' }
  - groupId: 'details'
    count: '>1'
    items:
    - { idRef: 'record', count: '>1' }
segments:
- id: 'header'
  name: "header"
  values:
  - { name: 'header', usage: M, type: String, length: 6 }
- id: 'record'
  name: 'record'
  values: 
  - { name: 'name', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
  - { name: 'code', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
  - { name: 'city', usage: M, type: String, length: 3 }
```